# The Xcode 4 console remains empty

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

It's so stupid. Suddenly, my console in Xcode 4 remains empty. I swear, I didn't do anything. ;) Even if I restart Xcode or reboot the system. What the heck is that?

EDIT: it's not in other project. I must have set something wrong. But what?

chris

[image: you see its running but theres no output]

Comment: Click the menu under "fivetwenty" next to the stop button and go to Edit Schemes.  Do you have a debugger enabled?

Comment: LLDB is enabled. And Lauch: Automatically. As far as I know, GDB is the old one. LLDB new. I tried with GDB and now it works smoothly again. Which one is the right one? EDIT: WAIT! It's not working. I just saw the "GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple versio..." stuff and thought its okay. But it does not show me any NSLogs.

Comment: I cannot find the mistake. What I did: 1. I copied all the files (a lot) in an empty projekt. In this app, the NSLog were shown up in the console. 2. The app stops at breakpoints, I think this means, the debugger is running.

Comment: 3. I tried to use "print" command instead of NSLog. But this doen't work either.

Answer (score 0):

By console do you mean Output section? Could you try with a little app with only an NSLog to see if there's any change?

Comment: As I said, it's only inside that specific project. Not in others.